XPath 1.0 predicate with number function doesn't match all nonzero values in XSLT input
I'm using the xsltproc command and getting unexpected output from a predicate using the number() function. I'm trying to use number()'s output as a boolean, with 0 treated as false and all other values treated as true. The goal is to select all elements with nonzero @original attribute.
It's easiest to explain via a reproducer.
Reproducer:

Input

<top>
  <constraint>
    <lifetime>
      <rule id="rule1" original="1"/>
      <rule id="rule2" original="1"/>
    </lifetime>
  </constraint>
  <constraint>
    <lifetime>
      <rule id="rule3" original="3"/>
      <rule id="rule4" original="0"/>
      <rule id="rule5"/>
    </lifetime>
  </constraint>
</top>


Stylesheet

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/|@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top">
    <xsl:for-each select="constraint/lifetime/rule[number(@original)]">
        <item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Actual output

<item>
  <rule id="rule1" original="1"/>
</item>


Expected output

<item>
  <rule id="rule1" original="1"/>
</item><item>
  <rule id="rule2" original="1"/>
</item><item>
  <rule id="rule3" original="3"/>
</item>

rule1, rule2, and rule3 should be included in the output because their @original values are nonzero. rule4 and rule5 should be excluded because @original is 0 and unset, respectively.
If I change from number(@original) to number(@original) = 1 or @original = '1', I get the expected results. I also get the expected result if I use an if within the for-each instead of using an XPath predicate:
    <xsl:for-each select="constraint/lifetime/rule">
        <xsl:if test="number(@original)">
            <item>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </item>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>


Edited to clarify the way I'm trying to use number() and to add rule elements that should not be included in the output, per feedback in the comments. My question has already been answered satisfactorily.

What exactly are you trying to select/check with rule[number(@original)]?

Your question would be a lot clearer if the example included some elements that are NOT supposed to be passed to the output, along with an explanation why. Note that the two variants which you claim return the expected result are very different from each other: one passes only rules whose original attribute is equal to 1; the other will pass any rule whose original attribute evaluates to any number except 0.

Thank you both, I edited the question to try to clarify. Side note, both of your responses in other threads have helped me immensely as I fumble through XSLT for a particular project I'm working on. (I'm stuck with 1.0 due to libxslt.)

When a predicate expression evaluates to a number, it is considered to be true if the number is equal to the context position. Your expression:
constraint/lifetime/rule[number(@original)]

is equivalent to:
constraint/lifetime/rule[position() = number(@original)]

and therefore evaluates as true only for those elements that are the first rule child of their parent lifetime.
See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates

"therefore evaluates as true only for those elements that are the first rule child of their parent lifetime." It would also be true for the third rule child if it has @original=3.

Yes, of course. I was referring to the input provided in the question.

Ahhh, thank you. Rookie mistake -- I assumed that if the predicate evaluated to a nonzero number, it would be converted to boolean true.

What you should be doing to implement your stated goal is <xsl:for-each select="constraint/lifetime/rule[boolean(number(@original))]">.  --- P.S. Note that (1) your output is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document (lacks a single root element) and (2) the identity transform template is redundant because it is not invoked.

Thanks again. My actual stylesheet, inputs, and outputs are significantly more complex and are well-formed. I trimmed most of the fat but left the identity template.

number(@original) returns 1 always in your case. I.e. the XPath constraint/lifetime/rule[number(@original)] means constraint/lifetime/rule[1], i.e. the first element rule in the element lifetime.
If you would like to check @original is number, then you need to use this condition:
constraint/lifetime/rule[number(@original) = @original]
or
constraint/lifetime/rule[string(number(@original)) != 'NaN']

I wanted to use it as a boolean, checking that @original is a nonzero number. This makes perfect sense though, thank you.
